# How to retrieve Ms access tables names from specific database using SQL in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Whenever I want to select tables names from specific Ms Access 2007 database, I use this SQL request:

```
SELECT name from msysobjects WHERE type=1 and flags=0
```

My VB.NET source code:

```
 Connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + _
                     "Data Source=" & Text1.Text
        Connection.Open()
        ' sql = "SELECT MSysObjects.Name AS table_name FROM MSysObjects"
        sql = "SELECT name from msysobjects WHERE Type = 1 And flags = 0"
        Dim commande As OleDbCommand
        commande = New OleDbCommand(sql, Connection)
        Dim dataReader As OleDbDataReader

        Try
            dataReader = commande.ExecuteReader()
            While (dataReader.Read())
                tableNameBox.Text = dataReader.GetString(0)
            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Problème de connection " & ex.Message())

        End Try
```

I always get this exception:

> no read permission on 'msysobjects'

My purpose is to show tables names in comboBox
Thank you

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it as a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).  Do not change this one after you've received a useful valid answer.  Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to access the system tables directly. You can use the `GetSchema` method to retrieve that information. For example, to retrieve a list of the "regular" (non-system) tables you can use this:

```vb
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(myConnectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim dt As DataTable = conn.GetSchema("TABLES", {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Console.WriteLine(dr("TABLE_NAME"))
    Next
End Using
```

For more information, see

[OleDbConnection.GetSchema Method (String, String())](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135983%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Gord Thompson, thank you for the your answer. I Really want to informe you that I have edited my post. Thank you. Best regards