# count all records in all tables in MS access database in vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I have a database in MS access and I have 4 tables in it. I want to count all the records of all the tables using vb.Net. Is there any oledbcommand command to count all the records in all the tables in the database?

```
    con1.Open()
    Dim Restrictions() As String = {Nothing, Nothing, "Table1", Nothing}
    Dim CollectionName As String = "Columns"
    Dim dt As DataTable = con1.GetSchema(CollectionName, Restrictions)
    For Each TableRow As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Console.WriteLine(TableRow.Item("COLUMN_NAME").ToString)
    Next
    con1.Close()
```

Comment: You should be able to combine [How can I get table names from an MS Access Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201282/how-can-i-get-table-names-from-an-ms-access-database) with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [tableName]` and add up the results.

Comment: Any idea how can I combine them. I mean the complete code with loop or something?

Comment: I think using this link, I can get table names but how to store and loop them dynamically and use select count? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446649/how-to-retrieve-ms-access-tables-names-from-specific-database-using-sql-in-vb-ne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created 2 functions. The first gets the table names by calling `GetSchema` on the connection. I excluded the system tables by checking if the name started with MS. I also excluded views by only adding TABLE_TYPE = TABLE.

The second function takes the list of table names and gets the count in each table. Note the brackets around table name in case the name contains a space.

```
Private cs As String = My.Settings.AccessAddressConnection

Private Function GetTableNames() As List(Of String)
    Dim TableNames As New List(Of String)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(cs)
        cn.Open()
        dt = cn.GetSchema("Tables")
    End Using
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        If Not row("TABLE_NAME").ToString.StartsWith("MS") AndAlso row("TABLE_TYPE").ToString = "TABLE" Then
            TableNames.Add(row("TABLE_NAME").ToString)
        End If
    Next
    Return TableNames
End Function

Private Function GetTotalRecords(lst As List(Of String)) As Integer
    Dim counts As Integer
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(cs),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cn.Open()
        For Each TName In lst
            cmd.CommandText = $"Select Count(*) From [{TName}];"
            counts += (CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar))
        Next
    End Using
    Return counts
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lst = GetTableNames()
    Dim Total = GetTotalRecords(lst)
    MessageBox.Show(Total.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: It shows an error Access address connection not a part of my settings

Comment: Yes, that is my connection string for testing. Substitute your connection string.

Comment: bro can you please help me with this question also :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70768873/change-value-of-selected-records-from-ms-access-database-in-datagridview-in-vb-n

Comment: Thanks for answering bro. I'm a noob in vb.net thanks for helping me. I marked this as answer. Was busy for some days so didn't see this